CORS Policy Implentation in .NET 6
Network trace error
I implemented CORS policy for an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, but when the frontend makes an API call, it still results in a CORS error. What could be the issue?
I have tried adjusting the URL and how I defined the policy, however it still prevents all origin from calling the API including the one specified.
please note that, the frontend is unable to call the api immediately the policy is defined.
    builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x =>
   x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);

//Cors Policy
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("https://apps.example.biz:8090")
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowCredentials();  // If you need to allow credentials
        });
});




//after other definitions in the pipeline then i have this.

app.UseHsts();
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/HangFireDash", new DashboardOptions
{
    Authorization = new[] { new HangfireAuthorizationFilter() }
});


app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();



app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


Repeat after me: images of code are not code. Images of code cannot be debugged.

Also your "UseCors" screenshot in isolation is about as useful as a chocolate teapot. You could have it in completely the wrong order with respect to other middleware.

Hi Kcee, could you share the network trace ? You can open the developer tools in browser and find the network tab, then we can find it. And we also can find the error message under the console tab.

Have you decorated your endpoints to use the AllowSpecificOrigin policy?

The location of your app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");  matters. if you can share the order of your middleware.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-8.0#credentials-in-cross-origin-requests

@JasonPan i just added an image of the network trace, I have also updated the code above to show more context.

@EsanjuBabatunde the attribute you mention is applicable only when configuring Cors policy for specific endpoints only, i am using a middle ware in the above instance

Hi Kcee, try to allow all origin and check the error exist or not. Then we can narrow down the issue step by step.

@JasonPan it works fine when i allow all origin

OK, this means the problem is related to CORS. Let me explain first, generally if there is an error before or after the CORS middleware, CORS error will also occur. So my suggestion is to move UseHangfireDashboard to after MapControllers middleware.

Hi Kcee, if suggestion not works above(check it in gist link), please use default Hangfire setting, like app.UseHangfireDashboard(). (Without using your custom HangfireAuthorizationFilter)
